# Const Generics - how to ensure that usize const is > 0

Tags: rust, types

Given sample struct:

```rust
struct S<const N: usize> {
    arr: [u32; N] // I want size to be N > 0
}
```

I want to have N > 0.

In other words, I want to limit available values of N to be from range `1...MAX_USIZE`, and not `0...MAX_USIZE`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To my knowledge it's not possible to add such constraints to const generics as of now, a workaround is a constructor that asserts `N > 0`:

```rust
struct S<const N: usize> {
    arr: [u32; N] // I want size to be N > 0
}

impl<const N: usize> S<N> {
    const fn new(arr: [u32; N]) -> Self {
        assert!(N > 0, "n must be greater than 0");
        S {
            arr
        }
    }
}

const FAILS_TO_COMPILE: S<0> = S::new([]);
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=ca000e781422e92eaf64edf79c4fa166)

results in:

```
error[E0080]: evaluation of constant value failed
  --> src/lib.rs:7:9
   |
7  |         assert!(N > 0, "n must be greater than 0");
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |         |
   |         the evaluated program panicked at 'n must be greater than 0', src/lib.rs:7:9
   |         inside `S::<0_usize>::new` at /rustc/fe5b13d681f25ee6474be29d748c65adcd91f69e/library/core/src/panic.rs:57:9
...
14 | const FAILS_TO_COMPILE: S<0> = S::new([]);
   |                                ---------- inside `FAILS_TO_COMPILE` at src/lib.rs:14:32
   |
   = note: this error originates in the macro `$crate::panic::panic_2021` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)
```

In non-const contexts, this is a runtime error.

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend `assert!()`ing in the constructor, like @sebpuetz said, however it *is* possible to do that. This is bad (see [this answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72467535/7884305) for an explanation why, and why this is a hard problem in general), but you can use associated items for that:

```rust
struct S<const N: usize> {
    arr: [u32; N],
}

impl<const N: usize> S<N> {
    fn new(arr: [u32; N]) -> Self {
        _ = <Self as AssertGt0>::VALID;
        
        Self { arr }
    }
}

trait AssertGt0 {
    const VALID: ();
}

impl<const N: usize> AssertGt0 for S<N> {
    const VALID: () = assert!(N > 0);
}

fn main() {
    // _ = S::new([]); // This fails compilation
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=a4ffbaab855ead0b79ececff91ac7df6).

You cannot do that on `where` clauses as far as I know, you have to use a constructor.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use a `where` clause you can do it like this:

```rust
#![feature(generic_const_exprs)]

pub enum Assert<const CHECK: bool> {}
pub trait IsTrue {}
impl IsTrue for Assert<true> {}

struct S<const N: usize> {
    arr: [u32; N]
}

impl<const N: usize> S<N>
where
    Assert<{N > 0}>: IsTrue
{
    const fn new(arr: [u32; N]) -> Self {
        S { arr }
    }
}
```

Note:

- this uses an unstable feature (`generic_const_exprs`) and you need to use the nightly compiler for this
- you can not define a custom error message (`mismatched types⏎expected constant false⏎ found constant true`)

More about const generics in rust can be found on [practice.rs](https://practice.rs/generics-traits/const-generics.html) (The Assert example can be found at the bottom of the page)