# Is it possible to instantiate new types using const generics in Rust?

Tags: generics, rust, const-generics

I am no expert in const generics but I've tried a couple of different approaches, all with issues, when trying out new type instantiations that involve operating on const generics, for example: when trying to increment base in this const generic struct from `K` to `K+1`.

```rust
// Given a Base<K> return a Base<K+1>
pub struct Base<const K:u32> {}
pub const fn base_bump<const K: u32, const L: u32>(b: Base<K>,) -> Base<L> {
    const L : u32 = K + 1;
    Base::<L> {}
}
```

Error :

```
error[E0401]: can't use generic parameters from outer function
 --> src/main.rs:5:20
  |
2 | pub const fn base_bump<const K: u32, const L: u32>(
  |                              - const parameter from outer function
...
5 |     const l: u32 = K + 1;
  |                    ^ use of generic parameter from outer function

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0401`.
error: could not compile `playground` due to previous error
```

my understanding is that the current state of const generics refuses to instantiate new `const generic`'s from other `const generics`s because `const generic`s are types before being values. IOW, `K` in

```rust
fn foo<const K: u32> () {}
```

is a type rather than a usual const value defined by `const K : u32 = 1;` Although I will strongly mention here that the error messages aren't pointing  the rational behind it.

Another issue arises when we try to do it like this:

```rust
pub struct Base<const K:u32> {}
// Given a Base<K> return a Base<K+1>
impl<const K : u32, const L: u32> Base<K> {
    pub fn base_bump(&self) -> Base<L> {
        todo!()
    }
}
```

Error:

```
error[E0207]: the const parameter `L` is not constrained by the impl trait, self type, or predicates
 --> src/lib.rs:3:27
  |
3 | impl<const K : u32, const L: u32> Base<K> {
  |                           ^ unconstrained const parameter
  |
  = note: expressions using a const parameter must map each value to a distinct output value
  = note: proving the result of expressions other than the parameter are unique is not supported
```

Is there any way to achieve what I am trying to do here or should I abandon const generics and use a regular field to define the base here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> my understanding is that the current state of const generics refuses to instantiate new const generic's from other const genericss because const generics are types before being values

This is not true, but there are multiple issues with your code.

First, as the compiler is pointing out, the `const L`  inside the function cannot refer to the function's generic parameter `K`. This is because `const`s are compiled separately, even if inside a function (the only difference is being inaccessible to code outside the function, i.e. scoping).

You should embed the computation:

```rust
pub const fn base_bump<const K: u32, const L: u32>(b: Base<K>) -> Base<L> {
    Base::<{ K + 1 }> {}
}
```

But this still have multiple problems. First, you're declaring you're returning `Base` with `L` chosen by the caller, but you are actually returning a constant `K + 1` and not `L`. You need to declare the function like:

```rust
pub const fn base_bump<const K: u32>(b: Base<K>) -> Base<{ K + 1 }> {
    Base::<{ K + 1 }> {}
}
```

But this errors with:

```
error: generic parameters may not be used in const operations
 --> src/lib.rs:2:74
  |
2 | pub const fn base_bump<const K: u32, const L: u32>(b: Base<K>) -> Base<{ K + 1 }> {
  |                                                                          ^ cannot perform const operation using `K`
  |
  = help: const parameters may only be used as standalone arguments, i.e. `K`

error: generic parameters may not be used in const operations
 --> src/lib.rs:3:14
  |
3 |     Base::<{ K + 1 }> {}
  |              ^ cannot perform const operation using `K`
  |
  = help: const parameters may only be used as standalone arguments, i.e. `K`
```

Because this thing requires [`#![feature(generic_const_exprs)]`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/76560). [With it it works](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=6aa83b296899f5ca050a4b45f11c1071), but raises a warning:

```
warning: the feature `generic_const_exprs` is incomplete and may not be safe to use and/or cause compiler crashes
 --> src/lib.rs:1:12
  |
1 | #![feature(generic_const_exprs)]
  |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  |
  = note: `#[warn(incomplete_features)]` on by default
  = note: see issue #76560 <https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/76560> for more information
```

See [this answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72467535/7884305) for why this feature is especially hard.

Comment: Even in simple functions, if we try to use `const generics` from the parameter of a function inside the function body it errors with 401 : can't use generic parameters from outer function. What is the meaning of this error?

Comment: @purple_turtle Can you give an example of what you mean?

Comment: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=c6f5b0a99400199dac55bb477a1a6bde

Comment: In other words, why is it not possible to instantiate a new type `const A : [u8; K] = [0; K]` in a function `fn foo<const K: usize>()` ? however `let A` compiles?

Comment: @purple_turtle "First, as the compiler is pointing out, the `const L` inside the function cannot refer to the function's generic parameter `K`. This is because consts are compiled separately, even if inside a function (the only difference is being inaccessible to code outside the function, i.e. scoping)."

Comment: @purple_turtle The array thing is a little tricky; the truth is that an array length compiles (almost) as if it was a `const` item.

Comment: When you say `const` item, is it a separate thing from a const generic?

Comment: @purple_turtle `const` item is `const NAME: Type = value;`.