# In Rust, what do arrays in where-clause mean?

Tags: rust

I'm experimenting with const expressions and generics in Rust and stumbled across the following problem. When I want to use the const generic argument (here `N`) indirectly like for example `N + 1`, the compiler tells me that I need to add a "where-bound" like this one:

`where [(); N + 1]:,`.

I don't understand the meaning of this. To me it looks like a constraint that says: "There is an array of type "empty tuple / unit" and "N + 1" entries which is bound to (nothing; as there is nothing after the colon)".

Can anyone help me understand the parts of this constraint?

Minimal example:

```rust
#![allow(unused)]
#![allow(incomplete_features)]
#![feature(generic_const_exprs)]

struct Foo<const N: usize> {}

impl<const N: usize> Foo<N>
where
    [(); N + 1]:,
{
    const BAR: [u32; N + 1] = [0u32; N + 1];
}

fn main() {}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you have no trait bounds, the type is only required to be well-formed, i.e. able to exist.

This is used in `generic_const_exprs` because *this type may not compile*. If, for example, `N` is `usize::MAX`, then `N + 1` will overflow and cause a compilation error. `generic_const_exprs` requires all potential errors to be reflected in the signature/header (and not just the body, see [an other answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72467535/7884305) for why). Because of that, the compiler requires you to repeat the expression in the header, to make sure that if the body can fail the header will also fail.

Comment: I just learned that `[u32; usize::MAX]` is actually a valid type, in spite of having a size of `4 * usize::MAX`.

Comment: @SvenMarnach As a type it is valid, but in reality you cannot create values with more than `isize::MAX` bytes.

Comment: Thank you! So the fact that the syntax reflects an array is not important but that the expression `N + 1` gets evaluated somehow to give it the possibility to fail. Ist that correct?

Comment: @Florian Technically, the type is evaluated, and that expression is just a part of it.